# SSMS Stored Procedures Missing

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

Good morning: I've recently moved offices and I was assigned a new userID and profile. My dilemma is that when logging into SSMS the stored procedures I've created under my old userID are no longer in the list.

How/where would I be able to retrieve those? I'll need to have server admins allow me access to my old login, if that's what I need to do? And then how do I bring them over to my new userID?

I meant to add that I first noticed this when I went to call a stored procedure from when refreshing a data table in Excel and it spit out an error.

Thanks in advance for all the suggestions/ input!

Robin

Answer (score 1):

the server admins got back to me, and it was a matter of updating my permissions and creating a new login with dbo on the database with my new userID and ADLogon.  After they performed that change, I was able to see all objects and run commands. Life is good!